# How does one check a HashSet for value containment?

Tags: java

```
 HashSet<int[]>  a = new HashSet<int[]>();
 int[] somestuff = {1, 2, 3};
 a.add(somestuff);
 int[] somestuff2 = {1, 2, 3};
 System.out.println(a.contains(somestuff2));
```

is `false`.

How do I check properly? Only when I check for `somestuff` do i get true, but even if the variable name/literal is not the same, but the values are, I want to get `true`. what method invocation allows me to get this done? I want to check for values...

Perhaps it has something to do with the contents being hashed in the set and also being dependent on the variable literal that was initially used to populate it

Comment: `int[]` doesn't implement "deep" equals.

Comment: Ok im gonna try arraylist then

Comment: Yep, ArrayList should work.  You'd have to have Integer elements, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct simple way to do what you want, however...

I would create a class that was composed of a `int[]` field and implemented `equals()` and a consistent `hashCode()` based on the contents of the array.

A `Set` if such objects could then use:

```
Set<MyClass> s;
MyClass o;
boolean b = s.contains(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this by calling a.contains() method. you have to iterate hash tabel and  check the values as the two arrays are identical.